# Why are some questions paled out in the queue?

Tags: support, questions

I noticed that some questions in the queue appear pale, for example [How did Descartes made a logical skeptic argument...](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/88593/9148) and [Why aren't Kripke semantics "syntax in disguise"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/88575/9148) It is similar to how highly downvoted answers are paled out, but these questions are not downvoted, and nothing appears to be wrong with them when they are opened. I do not recall seeing something like that before, does it mean something?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean queue like in review queue or main page?

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking The main page, both Newest and Active. What is the difference between a logical truth and a tautology? is like that on the latter.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots rather than just links?

Comment: @curiousdannii Done.

Comment: Have you set any tags as ignored?

Comment: @curiousdannii Not intentionally, but that is what it was. Thank you.